# C# How do I get the sum of all digits in a string, that is too long to convert into an integer?

Tags: c#

I have a string that consists of 11 digits(might be more or less at another time). This is too long to convert into an integer so I don't know how to get the sum of the digits.

I have tried:

```
string numberString = "84610467228";
int sumNumbers = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberString.Length; i++) {
   sumNumbers = sumNumbers + numberString[i];
}
```

But this doesn't work because numberString[i] is a char and not an integer.

What I wanted to do, by converting the string into an integer was:

```
string numberString = "84610467228";
int number = int.Parse(numberString);
int sumNumbers = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < numberString.Length; i++) {
   sumNumbers = sumNumbers + number%10;
   number = number / 10;
}
```

But the string is too long to convert into an integer. Is there a way of converting a long string into an integer or is there another way to solve this?

Comment: using `long` instead `int` ?

Comment: Just convert char to int with int.Parse in your first approach.

Comment: @Selvin it was really that easy. Thank you!

Comment: A loop isn't necessary either; LINQ makes this as compact as `numberString.Sum(c => c - '0')`.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should use `long` or `decimal` or `double` instead, and you can use `long.parse("Your sting")` to change `string` into `long` or for any other types you can use `parse` function.

Comment: Recommend using `tryparse` then `parse`